# Parsing comma delimited string with regex

Tags: javascript, regex, csv

There's a comma delimited string that I need to parse with JavaScript. The string is pulled from a CSV file. The string will be split by either \r\n, \n, or \r. The first row are the headers.

```
var str = 'firstname,middlename,lastname,address1,address2,city,st,zip,Custom01,Custom02,Custom03,Custom04,Custom05,Custom06,Custom07,Custom08,Custom09,Custom10,Custom11,Custom12,Custom13,Custom14,Custom15,Custom16,Custom17,Custom18,Custom19,Custom20 \n K,,P,123 ST,,CENTENNIAL,CO,80122-3011,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, \n K,,P,123 ST,,AURORA,CO,80013-2355,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, \n K,,P,123 ST,,LAKEWOOD,CO,80228-5332,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,';
```

I need to do two things.

- Make sure address1, city, st, and zip are not empty.
- Make sure zip is only 5 numbers.

Been testing some examples on regext101.com without any luck. Not even getting close to what's needed. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I have no idea what do your points mean. What specifically have you tried, either way?

Comment: If this `^(?:[^,]*,){3}([ ]*[^ ,][^,]*),[^,]*,([ ]*[^ ,][^,]*),([ ]*[^ ,][^,]*),(\d{5}),` matches it passes your test.

Comment: Thank you sln! Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

This is the code that I used thanks to sln. It uses regex to parse through a comma delimited string from a csv file using the criteria listed in my original question.

```
for (i = 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var sample = rows[i].match(/^(?:[^,]*,){3}([^,]+),[^,]*,([^,]+),([^,]+),(\d{5})/gm);
    if (sample === null) {
        alert('Either the address1, city, st, or zip is blank. Or zip is more then 5 digits.');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you need regex. String split will do what you want: [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

```
var str = 'firstname,middlename,lastname,address1,address2,city,st,zip,Custom01,Custom02,Custom03,Custom04,Custom05,Custom06,Custom07,Custom08,Custom09,Custom10,Custom11,Custom12,Custom13,Custom14,Custom15,Custom16,Custom17,Custom18,Custom19,Custom20 \n K,,P,123 ST,,CENTENNIAL,CO,80122-3011,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, \n K,,P,123 ST,,AURORA,CO,80013-2355,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, \n K,,P,123 ST,,LAKEWOOD,CO,80228-5332,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,';

var str_parts = str.split(',');

var address1 = str_parts[3];
var city = str_parts[5];
var street = str_parts[6];
var zip = str_parts[7];
```

I've leave checking that these are not empty as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: That is a lot of overhead. A simple regex might be quicker. Although `split` spells with less characters.

Comment: I think good code should be readable. I know which one I'd rather find.

Comment: Probably, _good code_ is subjective. Regex is readable if [formatted](http://www.regexformat.com) and used with the expanded modifier `/../x`